# What is the "on" keyword in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm a student learning ruby and I wasn't sure what "on" does in this code.

https://github.com/cinchrb/cinch/blob/master/examples/basic/seen.rb

For example,

```
on :channel do |m|
  @users[m.user.nick] = Seen.new(m.user.nick, m.channel, m.message, Time.new)
end
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: It's best to copy the code inline rather than linking externally, especially to a repository where the code is expected to change routinely.

Comment: Its apparently a method, not a keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a keyword, but a simple instance method called on the `Cinch::Bot` object you just created. The block you're passing to `Cinch::Bot.new` is evaluated against that new object (https://github.com/cinchrb/cinch/blob/master/lib/cinch/bot.rb#L363). It's a neat trick called a "DSL" (Domain-Specific Language): it looks like magic keywords or global methods, but it's really just methods called on a normal object.

Looks like `on` is defined in https://github.com/cinchrb/cinch/blob/master/lib/cinch/bot.rb#L188.

The code could instead be written like this:

```
bot = Cinch::Bot.new
bot.on :channel do |m|
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`on`  is a method on `Cinch.Bot`: https://github.com/cinchrb/cinch/blob/master/lib/cinch/bot.rb#L188